# CSS media print issues (PC and mobile)

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I got a wrapper that user can print each time the button clicked.

First of all:

```
    @page {
        size: A4 landscape !important;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
   }
```

Size landscape works perfect on PC but not working on mobile (tested in iPhone and Android)

Also I define exact A4 size 297 on width and 210 on height but nothing changes.

---

background-color and background (for color) works perfect on PC, not working in mobile

---

can't make center an element on a page. I code like this:

```js
   @media print {
 @page {
        size: A4 landscape !important;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
   }
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
   }
   body {-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;print-color-adjust: exact;}
    .page {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
   }
    .page-middle {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
   }
    .page-middle-inner {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
   }

      .pdf-before-item{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #ddd !important;
        border-radius: 20px !important;
        page-break-before: always;
        page-break-after: always;
        break-inside: avoid;
        list-style: none;
    }   
    .pdf-before-item p{
        height: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 120px;
        color: #000;
        vertical-align: middle;
        break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

```html
                <li class="pdf-before-item">
                  <p>ali</p>
                </li>
```

height: 100% on pdf-before-item and p inside make no diffrence and make height not bigger than the text font size.

---

Another thing is in some PCs Print paged contain header and footer that have a text of the site url and date and time of print. How can I remove this?

---

I searched the stack for similar question but it didn't fit to my needs.

Any useful help is much appreciated.

Comment: should be some solution to these. current progress is creating cataloge with power point. we spend time to make it dynamic